# Historical ad set budget

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if there was any way to get the ad set budget in history? When I request it in the params it will always give me the current daily budget

Example request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_${id}/adsets?fields=daily_budget,lifetime_budget,insights.fields(clicks, conversions).time_range({'since':'2019-11-14','until':'2019-11-14'})
```